# Saving a webpage along with its animation

Tags: google-chrome, bash, download, webpage, save-as

I'm looking for a way to save a wepgage along with its animation ([example](https://www.complexity-explorables.org/explorables/swarmalators/)).

I tried the chrome extension Save Page WE, the right click->save as, and the bash command:

```
wget --page-requisites https://www.complexity-explorables.org/explorables/swarmalators/
```

But these methods do not download the webpage along with its animation.

Answer (score 0):

The following website allows to download webpage along with its animations:

https://www.toolsbug.com/website-copier-online.php